# jQuery inside a kendo inline template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have jQuery run inside of an *inline* template?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have an inline template that contains a form that the user fills out to submit back to my controller.  I have a set of radio buttons on the form.  If they click on the last radio button, I need my textarea to appear and be required for form submission.

Here's the code that invokes the window that uses the template:

```
function onRejectClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#Reject").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(rejectTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

Here's my template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rejectTemplate">
<div id="reject-container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RejectConcern", "Filter", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "rejectConcern", @style = "width:100%", @class = "k-content" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="#= data.id #" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <label>Reason</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButton("reasonForRejection", "NotQuestion", false, new { @id = "reasonForRejection" })Concern is not a question and will not be answered
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButton("reasonForRejection", "Inappropriate", false, new { @id = "reasonForRejection" })Concern contains inappropriate language and will not be answered
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButton("reasonForRejection", "Irrelevant", false, new { @id = "reasonForRejection" })Concern is not relevant to our business/operation and will not be answered
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButton("reasonForRejection", "Personal", false, new { @id = "reasonForRejection" })Concern is about an individual, a specific group, or area and will not be answered
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButton("reasonForRejection", "Other", false, new { @id = "reasonForRejection" })Other
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td>
                @Html.TextArea("answer",
                    new
                    {
                        @id = "answer",
                        @name = "answer",
                        @class = "k-textbox",
                        @placeholder = "Enter the reason for rejection here.",
                        @validationmessage = "The reason for rejection is required.",
                        @style = "width: 600px; min-width:600px; max-width:69%; height:200px",
                        @maxlength = "1000"
                    }
                )
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button type="submit" id="rejectConcernButton" class="k-button">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
</script>
```

How can I use jQuery to show/hide the answer textarea field and make it required  depending on if the last radio button is checked or not?  If jQuery isn't possible, can it be done via regular JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can be done in javascript, it can be done in jQuery in this case. I mean, if you could use a javascript code, you could use a jQuery code as well. I suggest you to set an event in the widget's main element. Every widget has a property called `element`, which gives you the main html element of the widget. So if you set an event in all radio boxes inside your widget, you will be able to manipulate the template generated content, e.g:

```
$($("#listView").data("kendoListView").element).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() { });
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uDUZA)

I'm not sure what widget you're using, but I used ListView in this demo.